# Como pegar o atributo "aria-selected" do mat-selection-list com angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

possuo um mat-accordion que possui um mat-selection-list de uma forma interna.

Eu vi que dentro desse mat-selection-list possui um atributo que chama aria-selected, preciso pegar os dados dos checkbox que estão com esse aria-selected marcado como true.

Como fazer isso?

O resultado do meu html renderizado

```html
<mat-list-option _ngcontent-c6="" checkboxposition="before" class="mat-list-item mat-list-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="-1" ng-reflect-checkbox-position="before" ng-reflect-value="[object Object],[object Object" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false">
    <div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]"></div>
    <mat-pseudo-checkbox class="mat-pseudo-checkbox mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked" ng-reflect-state="checked" ng-reflect-disabled="false">
    </mat-pseudo-checkbox>
    <div class="mat-list-text">
       <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="container">
         <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="row">
          <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-md-12">
              Radiologia
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </mat-list-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode atribuir uma referência de variável template para ele, #accordion, e passar ela pra dentro do metodo que vc precisa ex:

```
change(#accordion)
```

e ai você procura a propriedade que você precisa dentro.

para saber mais sobre https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax, template reference variable